# Adding a bool in MVC 4, edit not saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am trying to create a draft option to my website. I did this by adding a bool value called draft.

//Model

```
[Required]
[Display(Name="Draft")]
public bool draft { get; set; }
```

On create the bool will work, however when trying to edit the bool value it doesn't save.

Here's my View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <h2>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.draft)</h2>
</div>
 <div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.draft)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.draft)
</div>
```

(I have tried with both editorfor and checkboxfor and still get the same problem)

Comment: Check the `model.draft` value before saving to make sure that you are getting the correct value from the model.

Comment: figured it out, it was in my controller, I wasn't updating the draft field. That's embarrassing, thanks for the help.